# image classification using Kera val_acc static value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hai I been trying to use image classification using keras, But when i fit the test and train data, loss, val_loss is 0 and val_accuracy is static value and not changing for each epoch. have provided the code and terminal output below. Please help me. Thank you

```
import numpy
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "Breast_MRI/Train",
    target_size=(32, 32),
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode='binary')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "Breast_MRI/Test",
    target_size=(32, 32),
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode='binary')


cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

'''Convolution'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[32, 32, 3]))

'''Pooling'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

'''2nd conventional layer'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

'''Flattening'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

'''Full Connection'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))

'''Output Layer'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

'''Training the CNN'''
cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
history = cnn.fit(training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=10)
```

and here is the terminal output:

```
Epoch 1/10
14/14 [==============================] - 12s 849ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2178 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 2/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 768ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2013 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 3/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 769ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2050 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 4/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 770ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1935 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 5/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 774ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2041 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 6/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 768ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1914 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 7/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 764ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1906 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 8/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 771ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2022 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 9/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 768ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2069 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 10/10
14/14 [==============================] - 11s 779ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2172 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
```

The thing is i need the value in loss, val_loss, val_accuracy. I dont know if its correct or not, because am new to Machine learning part. Please help me

Comment: Change loss into: `binary_crossentropy`

Comment: @Frightera Thanks bro, Now the loss and val_loss is printing, But what about the val_accuracy, which seems to be still static

Comment: That's probably about the model's complexity, I'd try to remove dropout layer (with an aggresive rate -> 0.8) first.

Comment: @Frightera it's still the same bro, even if i add or remove dropout layer, there will be no changes.

Comment: Have you tried using a different optimizer like sgd for example?

Comment: @AbhilashRajan no, bcz i only see this in google

Comment: @AbhilashRajan no bro, haven't tried any, because I found only this on google and i didnt did much of search either

Answer (score -1):

Use accuracy output printing only when you need it. And when need, please select suitable accuracy metrics for you and include required stuff. For simple approach, which I suppose is suitable for your purpose for monitoring the performance of training, please follow example below, done by modifying your code. Also, test different loss parameters as proposed in comments and see the effect.

```
import numpy
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

'''Convolution'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[32, 32, 3]))

'''Pooling'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

'''2nd conventional layer'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

'''Flattening'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

'''Full Connection'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))

'''Output Layer'''
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

'''Training the CNN'''
cnn.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adam") #, metrics=['accuracy'])
#history = cnn.fit(training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=10)

#Let's test...with a simulated model ... 
import numpy as np

simu_training_set_x=tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(10,32,32,3))
simu_training_set_y=tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(10,1))
history = cnn.fit(simu_training_set_x, simu_training_set_y, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Hai bro, I didnt understand what you meant to say, can you please explain it a bit if dont mind

Comment: Not able to see your full code or data, thus want to say first design (try & error) different achitectures and settings to see does when the "fit" begin to give good results. Is the size and amount of the data proper, etc... After being confident with all the parametrs (loss etc) add the metrics feature and take the accuracy also it into account, and "balance" between loss and accuracy, and this way get a practically working solution in your hands.